# mysql - sql - remove header from sql query - phpMyAdmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, response-headers

MySQL running in phpMyAdmin

```
SELECT max(reg_no) FROM `a_databasefield` ORDER BY reg_no LIMIT 1
```

results in;
`max(reg_no)` is
1722319

I want to remove the header completely. I want 1722319
-N etc does not work. and causes a SQL error.
-N `SELECT max(reg_no) From` a_databasefield `ORDER BY reg_no LIMIT 1;` does not work.

The one request that I do ask of any responder is to first check their answer by running their test in their phpMyAdmin MySQL database 'SQL' area

Comment: Please could you give a real output to show what you mean by headers? I am not at home and do not have access to PHPmyadmin.

Comment: max(reg_no)
1722348

Comment: You can't and why would you want to.